# Tomcat JavaMelody strange error ThreadDeath

Tags: java, tomcat, java-melody

Java Melody is generating a error running on Tomcat and I have no idea how to solve it.

```
java.lang.ThreadDeath
  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:836)
  at net.bull.javamelody.Action.stopThread(Action.java:388)
  at net.bull.javamelody.Action.killThread(Action.java:374)
  at net.bull.javamelody.Action.execute(Action.java:227)
```

This error is being throw 18 times.

What can I do? There is not much information about it on the web.

We know it because we have a error logger in a MySQL table and there is 18 records on it with this error.

There is a chance is the click on the console button the error would be throw to a particular user. I mean, if I click abort button in a console or so the user will see any error?

Comment: Are you clicking on the `kill thread` button from the console ? Under what conditions are these errors thrown ?

Comment: I dont know i know it because we have a error logger in a mysql table and there is 18 records on it with this error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused when you use the deprecated `stop()` method to kill a thread. The stack trace indicates that someone did click on the `kill thread` button.

```
net.bull.javamelody.Action.killThread(Action.java:374)
```

[ThreadDeath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html) is an Error that you cannot recover from. I'd recommend using `BASIC` authentication on your monitoring URLs and ensuring that threads are not killed. `stop()` has been deprecated and killing individual threads in the application is never recommended under any circumstance.